# Illegal use of Floating point error while using "pow()" in C

Tags: c

I am getting "Illegal use of floating point" error in line no 8,10 and 12.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{   int p,i,c=0;
    scanf("%d",&p);
    for(i=11;i>=0;i--)
    {   if((p==pow(2,i))&&(p%pow(2,i)==0))      //here
            c++;
        else if((p/pow(2,i)!=0)&&(p%pow(2,i)!=0))   //here
        {       c++;
            p=p%pow(2,i);               //here
        }
    }
    printf("%d",c);
    getch();
}
```

I think there is a problem while calculating the remainder of p using the pow() funciton.
Please help me.

Comment: You should not be using `pow`. Did you read its documentation? Instead of `pow(2,i)`, use `(1<<i)`.

Comment: In c @Magisch  (******)

Comment: didn't get you? what are you both saying @BLUEPIXY and David Schwartz

Comment: `pow()` will return a `double` value, type cast it to `int`.

Comment: @DeepakTalan What's don't you get? I'm saying that instead of `pow(2,i)`, you should use `(1<<i)`, since it does what you want. You should read the documentation for `pow`, so you can see that it does not do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `float` or `double` value for modulo (`%`). The value for modulo needs to be an integer, which is what your compiler is telling you about when it gives you the error "Illegal use of floating point"

You are not supposed to use the modulo operator for anything else then

```
<integer value>%<integer value>
```

If you just want to evaluate your `double` as if it was an `int` (without rounding), then you can just cast the `double` to `int`.

Like this:

```
p%(int)(pow(2,i))!=0
```

Comment: then how do i do it ? is there a way i can achieve the same result?

Comment: @DeepakTalan Considering your results are undefined, no. What exactly did you want to do anyways? The mathemathical operation of modulo only works for whole numbers.

Comment: problem solved , i just saved the value of pow in different variable by type casting it........................will be removing the question from here

Comment: @DeepakTalan Thats not how this QA site works. Removing the question is not permitted once answers are posted. The question will remain as help to future readers with the same problem. Read [help] and [ask]. Also consider accepting the answer that helped you the most with the green checkmark.